# How to select columns based on count of number of records returned?

Tags: sql

This is the table I have

```
| prdntVrsnNum | matlNum | wrkCtrCd | ritmValFromDt | versnValFromDt | parmVldFromDt | rtgTypeCd | rtgGrpCd | rtgNodeNum | charVal |
| ------------ | ------- | -------- | ------------- | -------------- | ------------- | --------- | -------- | ---------- | ------- |
| V001         | 96228   | TO-HCH2  | 20170407      | 20170407       | 20170407      | N         | 50020937 | 1          | 7       |
| V001         | 96228   | TO-HCH2  | 20170407      | 20170407       | 20170407      | N         | 50020937 | 1          | 7       |
| V001         | 96228   | TO-HCH2  | 20170407      | 20170407       | 20180101      | N         | 50020937 | 1          | 7       |
| V001         | 96228   | TO-HCH2  | 20170407      | 20170407       | 20180101      | N         | 50020937 | 1          | 7       |
| V003         | 197774  | TOU-A16  | 20181210      | 20181207       | 20190107      | N         | 50018492 | 6          | 1       |
| V003         | 197774  | TOU-A16  | 20181210      | 20181207       | 20190107      | N         | 50018492 | 6          | 1       |
| V001         | 66850   | LI-LIN2  | 20180101      | 20141211       | 20141211      | N         | 50018966 | 1          | 5       |
| V001         | 66850   | LI-LIN2  | 20180101      | 20141211       | 20151227      | N         | 50018966 | 1          | 4.5     |
| V001         | 66850   | LI-LIN2  | 20180101      | 20141211       | 20141211      | N         | 50018966 | 1          | 5       |
| V001         | 66850   | LI-LIN2  | 20180101      | 20141211       | 20151227      | N         | 50018966 | 1          | 4.5     |
```

Desired Result:

```
TOU-A16/V003/197774/20181210
TO-HCH2/V001/96228/20180101
LI-LIN2/V001/66850/20180101
```

Requirements/Conditions:

Having `prdntVrsnNum`, `matlNum`, `wrkCtrCd` as key columns,

1. Delete duplicates according to `rtgTypeCd`, `rtgGrpCd`, `rtgNodeNum`, `parmVldFromDt`, `charVal`
2. If no records found, do nothing.
3. If one record found, take `ritmValFromDt` for concatenation
4. If multiple records found, see how many records have `parmVldFromDt` >= `ritmValFromDt`

   4.1. If one record found, then use `ritmValFromDt` for concatenation.

   4.2. If multiple records found, then use `parmVldFromDt` for concatenation.

---

Intermediate result which I am using for explanation:

```
SELECT distinct * from mytable;

| prdntVrsnNum | matlNum | wrkCtrCd | ritmValFromDt | versnValFromDt | parmVldFromDt | rtgTypeCd | rtgGrpCd | rtgNodeNum | charVal |
| ------------ | ------- | -------- | ------------- | -------------- | ------------- | --------- | -------- | ---------- | ------- |
| V001         | 96228   | TO-HCH2  | 20170407      | 20170407       | 20170407      | N         | 50020937 | 1          | 7       |
| V001         | 96228   | TO-HCH2  | 20170407      | 20170407       | 20180101      | N         | 50020937 | 1          | 7       |
| V003         | 197774  | TOU-A16  | 20181210      | 20181207       | 20190107      | N         | 50018492 | 6          | 1       |
| V001         | 66850   | LI-LIN2  | 20180101      | 20141211       | 20141211      | N         | 50018966 | 1          | 5       |
| V001         | 66850   | LI-LIN2  | 20180101      | 20141211       | 20151227      | N         | 50018966 | 1          | 4.5     |
```

From the above table, now I should reduce it to the following final table, which I will use for concatenation.

```
| prdntVrsnNum | matlNum | wrkCtrCd | ritmValFromDt | versnValFromDt | parmVldFromDt | rtgTypeCd | rtgGrpCd | rtgNodeNum | charVal |
| ------------ | ------- | -------- | ------------- | -------------- | ------------- | --------- | -------- | ---------- | ------- |
| V001         | 96228   | TO-HCH2  | 20170407      | 20170407       | 20180101      | N         | 50020937 | 1          | 7       |
| V003         | 197774  | TOU-A16  | 20181210      | 20181207       | 20190107      | N         | 50018492 | 6          | 1       |
| V001         | 66850   | LI-LIN2  | 20180101      | 20141211       | 20141211      | N         | 50018966 | 1          | 5       |
| V001         | 66850   | LI-LIN2  | 20180101      | 20141211       | 20151227      | N         | 50018966 | 1          | 4.5     |
```

EDIT: Further explanation:

- `V001|96228|TO-HCH2` comes under condition `4.2`.
- `V003|197774|TOU-A16` comes under condition `4.1`.
- `V001|66850|LI-LIN2` I think this condition comes by choosing `ritmValFromDt` since that's the greater one and we don't have any record for this combination having `parmVldFromDt >= ritmValFromDt` But I'm not certain about this though.. :(

---

DB-Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qZLyGdyv2spYe3ZokZhYAP/1

---

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
CONCAT(wrkCtrCd, '/', prdntVrsnNum , '/', matlNum , '/', ritmValFromDt)
AS outputCol
FROM mytable;

| outputCol                    |
| ---------------------------- |
| TO-HCH2/V001/96228/20170407  |
| TOU-A16/V003/197774/20181210 |


SELECT
DISTINCT
CONCAT(wrkCtrCd, '/', prdntVrsnNum , '/', matlNum , '/',
      CASE
        WHEN parmVldFromDt >= ritmValFromDt THEN parmVldFromDt
        ELSE ritmValFromDt
      END)
AS outputCol
FROM mytable;

| outputCol                    |
| ---------------------------- |
| TO-HCH2/V001/96228/20170407  |
| TO-HCH2/V001/96228/20180101  |
| TOU-A16/V003/197774/20190107 |
```

---

**NOTE**

1. Please be as vendor neutral as possible when using SQL. This is not in my hands. I am not querying from source, so my hands are tied. Some vendor specific functions may be available, but this is not a guarantee.
2. In the db-fiddle, MySQL (and the version used) is for illustration purpose only. As stated previously, I am not querying from an RDBMS, I am querying from a grid, so I have to adjust with what is available and how it is available in the grid.

Comment: imho the simplest solution to this would be to first create a query that produces the answers/evaluations to all the conditions (1., 2., 3., 4.1 and 4.2) for every prdntVrsnNum-wrkCtrCd combination via `GROUP BY` - let's say it's query Q. then you create the outputCol depending on the values calculated in Q (join Q) by creating with the case statement - which you already may master. There might be some vendor specific black magic that might make it possible without the join of the aggregate ... but you wanted it to be vendor unspecific ;o)

Comment: @Jakumi I don't know how to write a case statement according to number of rows returned. That's one of the parts where I am stuck.

Comment: @Jakumi you can give a vendor specific black magic if you want, I can check in my environment if it is available/enabled. :)

Comment: @Jakumi I have posted an answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have defined your conditions correctly.  In particular, you for the last condition, you seem to want the latest date.

I would go for window functions for this.  I think the logic is:

```
SELECT CONCAT(wrkCtrCd, '/', prdntVrsnNum , '/', matlNum , '/',
              (CASE WHEN cnt = 1 OR cnt_gt = 1
                    THEN ritmValFromDt
                    ELSE parmVldFromDt
               END)
             ) AS outputCol,
             ritmValFromDt,parmVldFromDt
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY prdntVrsnNum, matlNum, wrkCtrCd) as cnt,
             SUM(gt_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY prdntVrsnNum, matlNum, wrkCtrCd) as cnt_gt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prdntVrsnNum, matlNum, wrkCtrCd, gt_flag ORDER BY parmVldFromDt DESC) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT prdntVrsnNum, matlNum, wrkCtrCd, ritmValFromDt, versnValFromDt, parmVldFromDt,
                   (CASE WHEN parmVldFromDt >= ritmValFromDt THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as gt_flag
            FROM mytable
           ) t
     ) t
WHERE (cnt_gt > 0 AND parmVldFromDt >= ritmValFromDt AND seqnum = 1) OR
      (cnt_gt = 0);
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d2eArfb4w4A958SupG1KYn/0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Conditions have been given to me by the functional team. I have asked them to come up with better explanations, but nothing so far. Not in my hands :(

Comment: @scientific_explorer . . . The last conditions suggests that you want multiple rows for a given combination.  However, you seem to only want the latest.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: Accepting your answer because it gives a very close result compared to my actual data. If you would like me to provide you with the data where it fails, please let me know, so that you can modify your query accordingly.

Comment: I have added a few more rows of data, for which your query fails to give desired output. Please have a look

Comment: I took your code and had some modifications to do with my actual data. In the end it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an answer I tried on the fiddle. Not sure if it will work in my actual system (have to test it out now). I am not sure if this is the best/only way to achieve it either.

```
select
distinct
concat(distinctTable.wrkCtrCd, '/', 
       distinctTable.prdntVrsnNum, '/', 
       distinctTable.matlNum, '/',
       case when countTable.cnt = 1 then min(distinctTable.ritmValFromDt)
       else max(distinctTable.parmVldFromDt)
       end
       ) as outputCol
from
(
  select
    tbl.prdntVrsnNum,
    tbl.matlNum,
    tbl.wrkCtrCd,
    count(*) as cnt
  from
    (select distinct * from mytable) as tbl
  group by
    tbl.prdntVrsnNum,
    tbl.matlNum,
    tbl.wrkCtrCd
) as countTable
inner join (select distinct * from mytable) as distinctTable
on countTable.prdntVrsnNum = distinctTable.prdntVrsnNum
and countTable.matlNum = distinctTable.matlNum
and countTable.wrkCtrCd = distinctTable.wrkCtrCd
group by
    distinctTable.prdntVrsnNum,
    distinctTable.matlNum,
    distinctTable.wrkCtrCd;

| outputCol                    |
| ---------------------------- |
| TO-HCH2/V001/96228/20180101  |
| TOU-A16/V003/197774/20181210 |
```

Comment: your 4th condition (comparing the count of rows where a certain condition is met or not met) can probably be prepared with `SUM(CASE WHEN parmVldFromDt >= ritmValFromDt THEN 1 ELSE 0) as cnt_whatever` and in your select you can use that information. However, this is very similar to Gordon's `gt_flag`, but won't work anymore in his query, but might work in yours (needs an additional group by somewhere in that sub-subquery)